# how to convert image into bytes [] in c#

Tags: c#

this will be a noob question.
I'm new to c#

I have a file upload server control that I am using to save images to server.

I have, in my library, an image resize function with this parameter:

```
byte[] resizeImage(byte[] image, int witdh)
```

that i am supposed to use.
now, i am saving my file to some path as upImage.saveas("filepath");

ok?

now, I want to resize this image and i cant figure how to convert that image to bytes???

where is the article to convert? everywhere i see, i can only see bytes to image but i want other way around..

please help?

Comment: no is of type upload control. where clients click browse button selects image in their my pictures and then saves it

Comment: If it's client side, then you can't run C# code

Comment: hehehe good joke, when client click save, page executes in server no? = kieren johnstone

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you mean convert the saved file to a `byte[]` array? If so, you can use [`File.ReadAllBytes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readallbytes.aspx):

```
byte[] imageBytes = File.ReadAllBytes("example.jpg");
```

If you want to grab the `byte[]` array directly from your [`FileUpload`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.aspx) control then you can use the [`FileBytes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.filebytes.aspx) property:

```
byte[] imageBytes = yourUploadControl.FileBytes;
```

Comment: @carlos: I don't know. They're usually subtly different ways to solve subtly different problems. Because I'm not sure *exactly* what your problem is I've made a couple of suggestions, hoping that one of them will match your exact requirements.

Answer (score 6):

Looks like you can save it to a `MemoryStream` then convert the `MemoryStream` to a byte array.  From [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/ImageConverter.aspx)

```
public byte[] imageToByteArray(System.Drawing.Image imageIn)
{
 MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
 imageIn.Save(ms,System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);
 return  ms.ToArray
}
```

Comment: `MemoryStream` *yeeeaaaaaauhhhhh*

Answer (score 1):

convert the file to bytes in fileuploadcontrol on post method

```
public ActionResult ServiceCenterPost(ServiceCenterPost model)
{
     foreach (var file in model.FileUpload)
     {
          if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
          {
             byte[] fileBytes = new byte[file.ContentLength];
             file.InputStream.Read(fileBytes, 0, Convert.ToInt32(file.ContentLength));
             string thumbpath = _fileStorageService.GetPath(fileName);
            _fileStorageService.SaveFile(thumbpath, fileBytes);
         }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, the short answer is

`File.ReadAllBytes("filepath");`

But the long answer is, it doesn't sound like you have any idea what's going on, so I suggest you make sure that the image is actually encoded the way you think it is (Is it actually a bitmap on disk, or is it compressed?  What does `resizeImage` actually do with the bytes and what kind of image does it expect?  Why doesn't `resizeImage` take an `Image` and just resize it with GDI+?)  Otherwise you might be in for a surprise.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Image.Save function, passing in a memory stream.  Once it completes, you can use MemoryStream.Read or MemoryStream.ToArray to recover the bytes.